# Combining classification and anomaly detection

Tags: machine-learning, classification, anomaly-detection

I want to build a system, that can classify known classes in a supervised way and at the same time tells if there is a new anomaly class it has not seen before. The user can then label that unknown class (as normal or a certain failure class) so it will be detected next time.

I can imagine two approaches:

A) 1 classification model - a high uncertainty / low confidence would indicate an unknown class

B) 1 classification model + 1 anomaly detection system (combine their outputs 'somehow', not sure what would be the best way).

Btw. it is about audio data.

Any idea or resources what is a good or best practise approach for this (I think common) requirement?

Comment: Say that you build it, initially it predicts two classes and marks one case as anomaly--if you train your classifier on single example it would badly overfit... What if on next iteration another case would be marked as anomaly--would you train for another single-observation class?

Comment: Do you have well-defined idea what an outlier will be? I think you are right to suspect that a 1+1 approach is better. That said use domain knowledge. Eg. If as you say these are sound data, and you expect speech utterances, check what the $F_0$ (fundamental frequency) of the recording are. If they are something rather outside norm (eg. $F_0$ ~50H i.e. a baritone talking out of a cave) probably they are outliers...

Comment: Yes it is about audio data, and it should detect failures based on anomalous noises. A challenge is that the same rare event which is not a failure would be always detected as anomaly. Another rare event could be a real anomaly. So I need some classification that can over-rule the anomaly detection.

Comment: Do you have an idea what is an "anomalous noise"? If yes, built a sample of "anomalous noises" and use them as third class.

Comment: No unfortunately not at the beginning. The idea is is to label the anomalous noises when they occur the first time, so that they will be classified next time. I could think of data augmentation to reduce overfitting a bit after the first examples.

Comment: So in this application we do not know what an anomaly is?

Comment: We don't know at the beginning which patterns an anomaly has. If an anomaly is detected, an expert can check if it was a false alarm (relabel it to normal) or a real failure (set failure label).

Comment: Sounds a bit similar to Active Learning, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning)

Comment: Can you say something more about the audio task in question? Eg is it about music or speech? What are the lengths of the audio of interest?

Answer (score 1):

The case where you want to detect that a certain input is not represented in the dataset, is sometimes referred to as "novelty detection", a slight variation on anomaly detection.

Your suggested approach A) is the simplest one (single model), so try that first.

If it does not work OK you could try a cascade of NoveltyDetector -> Classifier. But the performance in the detector can easily become a limitation, as well as disagreement between the detector and classifier.
You can see the choice of architecture as a hyperparameter, and approach it in the standard supervised learning way: Use a held-out testset and cross-validation in order to determine what works best for your dataset.

A good starting point is to have a solid feature representation. An audio embedding is a compact representation of a short period of audio (few seconds). The AudioSet project has released strong pretrained CNN models called VGGish that can be used to produce such embeddings. [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/audioset). These are 128 dimensional with on orthogonal basis, which makes it easily to build machine learning on top using simple methods and very small datasets. Linear models, kNN and tree-based methods should all do pretty well, both for classification and novelty detection.

> The user can then label that unknown class...so it will be detected next time.

Learning from a single sample (one-shot learning) is very challenging, as is automatically updating the model (online learning). For that reason it is not commonly done these days, and best practice is scarce.